# Display data to the view

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm having trouble displaying data in my view. I need to display `teacher's remark` in the view.

I placed this in my controller `<pre>';print_r($data);die`
and $data['exam_result'] outputs the teacher's remark. However, I'm still having issues displaying it in the view.

Controller:

```
  public function view($id)
    {
        $data['exam_result'] = $this->examgroupstudent_model->searchStudentExams($student['student_session_id'], true, true);

        $this->load->view('layout/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('student/studentShow', $data);
        $this->load->view('layout/footer', $data);
    }
```

Model:

```
public function searchStudentExams($student_session_id, $is_active = false, $is_publish = false) {
        $inner_sql = "";
        if ($is_active) {
            $inner_sql = "and exam_group_class_batch_exams.is_active=1 ";
        }
        if ($is_publish) {
            $inner_sql .= "and exam_group_class_batch_exams.is_publish=1 ";
        }
        $sql = "SELECT exam_group_class_batch_exam_students.*,exam_group_class_batch_exams.exam_group_id,exam_group_class_batch_exams.exam,exam_group_class_batch_exams.date_from,exam_group_class_batch_exams.date_to,exam_group_class_batch_exams.description,exam_groups.name,exam_groups.exam_type FROM `exam_group_class_batch_exam_students` INNER JOIN exam_group_class_batch_exams on exam_group_class_batch_exams.id=exam_group_class_batch_exam_students.exam_group_class_batch_exam_id  INNER JOIN exam_groups on exam_groups.id=exam_group_class_batch_exams.exam_group_id WHERE student_session_id=" . $this->db->escape($student_session_id) . $inner_sql . " ORDER BY id asc";


        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        $student_exam = $query->result();

        if (!empty($student_exam)) {
            foreach ($student_exam as $student_exam_key => $student_exam_value) {
                $student_exam_value->exam_result = $this->examresult_model->getStudentExamResults($student_exam_value->exam_group_class_batch_exam_id, $student_exam_value->exam_group_id, $student_exam_value->id, $student_exam_value->student_id);
            }
        }
        return $student_exam;
    }
```

View:

```
Teacher's Remark: <?php echo $student->teacher_remark; ?>;
```

Comment: what does `echo '<pre>';print_r($data);die;`  output? (place it in your controller before you load the views). In your example you don't have an array `$data['student']`defined, so how would that line `echo $student->teacher_remark;`in your view work?

Comment: @Vickel after doing what you said, I noticed what I was doing wrong. The part that correctly outputs the teacher remark is $data['exam_result']. But how do I display in view? I have updated my code.

Comment: Yeah! Thanks so much. I've figured it out

Comment: you are welcome to write a self-answer, check [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Your answer, explaining what you did wrong in the 1st place and how you resolved the problem might help other users with a similar problem, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did in my view

```
Teacher's Remark: <?php echo $exam_value->teacher_remark;?>
```

Comment: I suppose you meant `$exam_result->teacher_remark`, also add a bit more around your answer, in order to explain what and why you changed your code.